# Material theme editor for linux/windows OS

Tags: material-design

I'm trying to implement material design on my site. There is a tool ["Material theme editor"](https://material.io/tools/theme-editor/) but it seems it's provided only for Sketch app on macOS.

Does anyone know if there is a similar plugin for any app on Linux or Windows?
Or will same plugin be created for Jetbrains tools for example to be used on these systems?

Thanks for any information in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Material Theme Editor is currently available only for the sketch spp but Google is considering to develop this to other platforms according to this tweet.

https://twitter.com/materialdesign/status/997159840391741440

Its already been 6 months but there seems to be no update on this still.

If you are using Adobe XD cc for prototyping then you get the Google Material UI kit from Below link.

https://www.adobe.com/products/xd/resources.html#panel-3